# English translation of Oseen's book on Hydrodynamics

Tags: fluid-statics, specific-reference

Is there an English translation of Oseen's 'Neure methoden und ergebnisse in der Hydrodynamik' available anywhere? I could not find it on Amazon. Google search didn't shed any light. I believe that this is a significant book in fluid mechanics and I am surprised not to find it translated into English.

Comment: If a German author uses (in most cases Springer or Birkhäuser) a German publisher to have his work appear in German, then the English translation is usually done within a few years, if there is a particular academic interest from the US. Even through you may consider it a valuable writing, this is so far not enough to make the same publisher pay a translator to have it written in English, too.

Comment: I couldn't find any translations from searching Cambridge University's library, which also searches other university collections. I agree it seems like an oversight for an important work.

Comment: The Cambridge scholars in Oseen's times were probably required to know one of German or French; they weren't pushed to desperation to have it translated. Let me check if I can get it translated for a charge.